# The simple task of iterating through an array. Which of these solutions is the most efficient?

Tags: c++, c, x86

Recently, I've been thinking about all the ways that one could iterate through an array and wondered which of these is the most (and least) efficient. I've written a hypothetical problem and five possible solutions.

**Problem**

Given an `int` array `arr` with `len` number of elements, what would be the most efficient way of assigning an arbitrary number `42` to every element?

**Solution 0: The Obvious**

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    arr[i] = 42;
```

**Solution 1: The Obvious in Reverse**

```
for (unsigned i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    arr[i] = 42;
```

**Solution 2: Address and Iterator**

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{   *arr = 42;
    ++arr;
}
```

**Solution 3: Address and Iterator in Reverse**

```
for (unsigned i = len; i; --i)
{    *arr = 42;
     ++arr;
}
```

**Solution 4: Address Madness**

```
int* end = arr + len;
for (; arr < end; ++arr)
    *arr = 42;
```

**Conjecture**

The **obvious** solutions are almost always used, but I wonder whether the subscript operator could result in a multiplication instruction, as if it had been written like `*(arr + i * sizeof(int)) = 42`.

The **reverse** solutions try to take advantage of how comparing `i` to `0` instead of `len` might mitigate a subtraction operation. Because of this, I prefer **Solution 3** over **Solution 2**. Also, I've read that arrays are optimized to be accessed forwards because of how they're stored in the cache, which could present an issue with **Solution 1**.

I don't see why **Solution 4** would be any less efficient than **Solution 2**. **Solution 2** increments the address and the iterator, while **Solution 4** only increments the address.

In the end, I'm not sure which of these solutions I prefer. I'm think the answer also varies with the target architecture and optimization settings of your compiler.

Which of these do you prefer, if any?

Comment: Did you try benchmarking them?

Comment: If you decide to benchmark them, you can also try `memset`.

Comment: @Kiril, memset sets characters rather than integers so it's not really suitable here.

Comment: `(unsigned i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)` will hopefully give you a fat warning on your compiler, because it is an eternal loop. Since an unsigned value is always larger than 0.

Comment: Good catch Lundin. As for solution 4 vs 2, John's right. variable i just acts as loop control variable which can be replaced with pointer arithmetic on arr. Also, it's not necessarily true that forward array access is better due to cache structure. A stride prefetcher with negative stride can prefetch cache blocks backward. However, forward access is usually optimized by architecture ISA for storage-storage instructions such as MVC

Answer (score 10):

Just use `std::fill`.

```
std::fill(arr, arr + len, 42);
```

Out of your proposed solutions, on a good compiler, neither should be faster than the others.

Comment: How does this method compare to the methods posted in the question ? Advantages and disadvantages other than ease of use ?

Comment: @VivekS for starters, it's a one-liner. That should be reason enough. Performance-wise, there should be no difference.

Comment: @VivekS Performancewise it depends on the optimization level of the standard library. It will likely perform very similar to the manual loop, however in theoretically the implementation could have some hand optimized vectorized solution for this case, which could outperform any reasonable manual approach.

Comment: @Grizzly: _optimized vectorized solution_ here isn't just theoretical; gcc does inline a vectorized `std::fill` as does Intel ICC (those two compilers I can test).

Answer (score 6):

The ISO standard doesn't mandate the efficiency of the different ways of doing things in code (other than certain big-O type stuff for some collection algorithms), it simply mandates how it *functions.*

Unless your arrays are billions of elements in size, or you're wanting to set them millions of times per minute, it generally won't make the slightest difference which method you use.

If you *really* want to know (and I still maintain it's almost certainly unnecessary), you should benchmark the various methods in the target environment. **Measure, don't guess!**

As to which *I* prefer, my first inclination is to optimise for *readability.* Only if there's a specific performance problem do I then consider other possibilities. That would be simply something like:

```
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
    arr[idx] = 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that performance is an issue here - those are, if at all (I could imagine the compiler producing the identical assembly for most of them), micro optimizations hardly ever necessary.

Go with the solution that is most readable; the standard library provides you with `std::fill`, or for more complex assignments

```
for(unsigned k = 0; k < len; ++k)
{
    // whatever
}
```

so it is obvious to other people looking at your code what you are doing. With C++11 you could also

```
for(auto & elem : arr)
{
    // whatever
}
```

just don't try to obfuscate your code without any necessity.

Answer (score 0):

For nearly all meaningful cases, the compiler will optimize all of the suggested ones to the same thing, and it's very unlikely to make any difference.

There used to be a trick where you could avoid the automatic prefetching of data if you ran the loop backwards, which under some bizarre set of circumstances actually made it more efficient. I can't recall the exact circumstances, but I expect modern processors will identify backwards loops as well as forwards loops for automatic prefetching anyway.

If it's REALLY important for your application to do this over a large number of elements, then looking at blocked access and using non-temporal storage will be the most efficient. But before you do that, make sure you have identified the filling of the array as an important performance point, and then make measurements for the current code and the improved code.

I may come back with some actual benchmarks to prove that "it makes little difference" in a bit, but I've got an errand to run before it gets too late in the day...